# Search Query in Linq with EF

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

Lets say I have the following classes for Entity Framework 5 Code First. I need to do a search of all the Industries or Divisions for an array of keywords, returning all the Leads that match any of the keywords. I also need to search the Name of the Lead for the same keywords. What I'm stuck on is how to search for **multiple** keywords.

Main Class

```
public class Lead
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Industry> Industries { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
}
```

Industry Class

```
public class Industry
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Lead> Leads { get; set; }
}
```

Division Class

```
public class Division
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Lead> Leads { get; set; }
}
```

Service / Repository Call

```
public IQueryable<Lead> GetByKeywords(string keyword)
    {
        var result = leadRepository.GetAll().Where
            (x => x.Industries.Any(i => i.Name == keyword)
            || x.Divisions.Any(d => d.Name == keyword)
            || x.Name.Contains(keyword));

        return result;
    }
```

The above query works for a single keyword. But it does not work if I have multiple words in the string and I want to match to any of the individual keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Lead> GetByKeywords(string[] keywords)
    {
        var result = GetAll().Where
            (x =>x.Industries.Any(i => keywords.Any(kw=>kw==i.Name))
            || x.Divisions.Any(d =>keywords.Any(k=>x.Name==k))
            || keywords.Any(kew => x.Name.Contains(kew)));

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This worked with one minor change (typo I think). The line: x.Divisions.Any(d =>keywords.Any(k=> k==d.Name)) I modified and the correct values are returned.

Comment: Ran into one issue. The last line. The Lead.Name (x.Name) can contain multiple words and the keywords need to match to any. Since Linq doesn't allow you to split a string (using string.split(' '), is there another way to do this in Linq.

Comment: What I tried was so much more complicated. This works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to split your string into a List and loop through each keyword.  Something like this...  (off the top of my head)

```
IQueryable<Lead> GetByKeywords(string allKeywords)
{
    List<string> keywords = allKeywords.Split(" ");
    var result = leadRepository.GetAll();

    foreach (string keyword in keywords)
    {
        result = result.Where
            (x => x.Industries.Any(i => i.Name == keyword)
            || x.Divisions.Any(d => d.Name == keyword)
            || x.Name.Contains(keyword));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Scottie. I didn't mark as answer as I preferred a solution 100% in Linq.